# Timer to shutdown

Tags: command-line, shutdown

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Intel NUC DN2820. And almost every night as I lie down to sleep I listen to music, and my NUC shuts down (On Windows). On Windows it has the easiest command ever in CMD: `Shutdown -s -t 1000`.

That doesn't work on Ubuntu I figured out, but I found this command: `Sudo shutdown 18:45`, for those who don't know, 18:45 is an example when the system will shut down.

I tried this in terminal: `Sudo shutdown 01:00` and I got a message in terminal '' E:/ can`t find the command''
The E: drive is my external drive, and C: is my SSD, what can I do to get it to shut down?

Thanks :)

Comment: you have two typo: 1) change `Shutdown` to `shutdown` and 2) change `Sudo` to `sudo`.  note uppercase **s**

Comment: Can you give me the exact command? :))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct command would be `sudo shutdown -h 23:45` - without the -h or -r switch it isn't a valid command (there are others - see man page).

Using +9 instead of the time gives you any easy way to say 'in 9 minutes'.

Any reference to E:/ tells us that there is some reference to a windows command going on here as linux has no E:/ which is partly why there are comments as to what you *really* typed, above - please copy/paste commands, don't re-type them!

Comment: Thanks! :D
I`ll try when I get home :)
So I can use sudo shutdown -h +9?

Comment: yes - or any other time period (minutes) you fancy. `now` works as well.

Comment: Okey, 'cus in Windows it's seconds. So correct me if wrong. I'll type this in terminal: sudo shutdown -h +20, than it'll shut down in 20 min?

Comment: @Swinzon yes, exactly. You can find out more about `shutdown` by running `man shutdown`. For seconds, use `-t`, for example `sudo shutdown -h -t 60` will shutdown in one minute. It is the same as running `sudo shutdown -h +1`.

Comment: Oh, okay. I like to sleep to music :) Is there any command to get my machine to sleep? Or is it just shutdown?

Comment: there's `sudo pm-suspend`, if you like. You could set this up as `sleep 39m ; sudo pm-suspend` to zap it in a while...

Comment: I didn't get it to work...

Comment: That's a shame, works on my ASUS eee... & desktop. What DID it do?

Comment: Nothing, I typed "sudo shutdown -h +30" than it took about 2 min and it got to a new command line, I watched a movie, it was about 1.3h and nothing happened...

Comment: Most odd! something must have killed the running shutdown - it _shouldn't_ just quit during the delay, obviously.. What happens with `sudo shutdown -h now`? Also might be worth checking `/var/log/auth.log` to check it did actually process the `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

`sudo shutdown -h +30` will let the system power off after 30 minutes.